# How to transform Rows into Column Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

How to transform Rows into Columns for the below table data in SQL serer

> Actual table

```
LabelID  |  LabelName
---------------------
    1    |  Label1
    2    |  Label2
    3    |  Label3
    4    |  Label4
    5    |  Label5
```

> Expected table

```
    1  |    2   |   3   |   4    |  5   
------------------------------------------
Label1 | Label2 | Labe3 | Label4 | Label15
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: Why tag 3 completely different versions of SQL Server, all of which are unsupported, and 2 of them **completely** unsupported. If you are using 2005, then you many of the answer you find it may well not work, as you're using technology that has had no support for 5~ years.

Comment: Do you have more rows for 1 or 2 or ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample query that might help you to achieve your required output. This query will work in case you have that 5 rows in real as well. In case of more rows and variety in data, you need to adjust the query as per your data and required output.

```
SELECT 
MAX(CASE WHEN LabelID = 1 THEN  LabelName END) [1],
MAX(CASE WHEN LabelID = 2 THEN  LabelName END) [2],
MAX(CASE WHEN LabelID = 3 THEN  LabelName END) [3],
MAX(CASE WHEN LabelID = 4 THEN  LabelName END) [4],
MAX(CASE WHEN LabelID = 5 THEN  LabelName END)[5]
FROM your_table
```